# String from getter is empty when called in another Project C#

Tags: c#, string, getter-setter

I am a total beginner in C# programming language. I am trying to use Getter and Setter in order to set the string in ProjectA and the retrieve it in Project B.

> Project B uses Windows Forms, and I wasnt to set the value of TextBox
>   with the retrieved string.
>
> Project A is a Console Project and it just reads out some stuff from
>   file and stores it in string, which I want to retrieve.

However, this is my call in Project B:

```
 string cardOwner = Transmit.Program.CardOwner;
            Debug.WriteLine("Card owner = " + cardOwner);
            tb_cardholder.Text = cardOwner;
```

And this is my Getter / Setter in Project A:

```
private static string _cardOwner;
  public static string CardOwner
        {
            get
            {
                return _cardOwner;
            }

            set
            {
                _cardOwner = value;
            }
        }

 _cardOwner = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bCardOwner);
```

*But in Project B I get "" empty string.*

I have included Project A in Project B (added Reference and wrote "using ProjectA").

Any ideas what's going wrong?

Thanks.

Comment: The context for the shown assignment to `_cardOwner` is unclear. Also, have you tried debugging and setting a breakpoint on all assignments to `_cardOwner` and `CardOwner.Set`?

Comment: where are calling your property to set the value

Comment: Hi Chrashmstr, I didn't debugg it, because I still haven't learnt that properly how it works.. in Android projects, luckily I didn't need to debugg it this way. I will check debugging to see if I find something.  _cardOwner is assigned in the Project A (I have pasted the code here 2nd paragraph, last line).

Comment: Hi @Prathyush I am calling my property in Project B (1st paragraph of code I posted). it is: string cardOwner = Transmit.Program.CardOwner;   Transmit is namespace of Project A and Program is its class.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just because you include a project and use its classes in your project B, it doesn't mean that you also use the *instances* of these classes.

Take the following class:

```
public class Test
{
    public string Message { get; set; }
}
```

You can put this class into a DLL project (`Tools`) and reference it from other projects, like a WinForms project `ProjectA` and  a console project `ProjectB`.

In both projects, you can write something like:

```
Test t = new Test() { Message = "Hello" };
```

That creates a new instance of the `Test` class, but the two running applications `ProjectA` and `ProjectB` do not exchange the data! They are completely separated.

The same is true for class properties.

Answer (score 0):

You can't share information between two different applications so easily. Static properties only share data within the same Application Domain, that is in most simple constellations within the same Windows process.

If you want to transfer data between two different processes, you need to use an explicit mechanism for interprocess communication.

Comment: Thanks for answer. What is such explicit mechanism ? How can I transfer static property over to another Project ?

Comment: This depends very much on the concrete setup. Does one of the executables start the other? Do they run at the same time and need to exchange data while they are running or do they run one after the other, etc

Comment: @AndroidNFC You can use pipes. Read here: https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/bb546102(v=vs.110).aspx

Answer (score 0):

When is this line executed?

```
_cardOwner = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bCardOwner);
```

You'll need to put that in a method and call that method (and knowing when the call happens will help you understand why `_cardOwner` is not set:

```
public static void Init()
{
    _cardOwner = System.Text.Encoding.ASCII.GetString(bCardOwner);
}
```

Then call this method somewhere that you know will be executed before you need `_cardOwner`:

```
Transmit.Program.Init();
string cardOwner = Transmit.Program.CardOwner;     
tb_cardholder.Text = cardOwner;
```